# Stack navigator slowing down with usage - React-native Android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have setup a React-Native Android app. It has a few screens, a login page and some other pages, but I am facing an issue where the app is slowing down with usage. After navigating between a few screens many times, the components fail to render, Icons dissappear and screen transitions slow down. If used extensively, I mean if I keep navigating and navigating, the app becomes unusable eventually. How can I fix this?

Please note- I have not used Redux or any router, Just stacknavigator. I thought it was an issue with the debug build, but I generated a signed APK and the issue persists there too.

How can I reset a stack navigator and remove all previous states from it to clear up memory?

Comment: Feels like memory leak

Comment: Yes it is. But how do I determine where it is?

Comment: Check how all the images should be recycled/deleted first

Comment: What navigation library?

Comment: Stack Navigator

Answer (score 0):

I went through the overall flow of the app, found that at some places the stack is not cleared, it keeps on building up. For instance when the user is prompted to log out, the stack was not cleared, instead more pages were added to the stack. When the user logs in and out a multiple number of times, the stack becomes that much bigger.

Also, I read somewhere that react-native on android runs on single thread, whereas it runs multithread in iOS.

Unlike native code, in react you have to take memory management very seriously. Remove event listeners in pages which will unmount.

This is the code I used to reset the stack in a few places.

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'

this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    key: null,
    actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'ParentStackScreen' })]
}))
```

Comment: "Also, I read somewhere that react-native on android runs on single thread, whereas it runs multithread in iOS."  Will there be any performance differences in IOS and Android? I have tested both the devices connected to same wifi network and resulted in no differences. )

Comment: I had zero issues when I ran on the iOS device, but started facing this issue when run on Android device. I think you feel the difference when the code is not optimized, like the one I have written now.

Comment: i see. I too came across few OS related issues  and solved them using Platform.OS .. Anyways thank you for quick response.

Comment: Sure. No mention.